# R CMD BATCH as normal user

Tags: windows, r

I can't run my R script via CMD BATCH, because when I run C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\bin\R.exe libPaths is `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.0\library` but when I run RStudio my libPath is `C:/Users/ac/Documents/R/win-library/3.1`

I have tried to prepend my r script with `commandArgs(R_LIBS = "C:/Users/ac/Documents/R/win-library/3.1")`

So how can I specify which lib to use?

I'm running Windows 8.

Comment: In your script, add another path to `.libPaths()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.libPaths` you can get a list of directorys where `R` is looking for Packages.

Just add the following line to your Script

```
.libPaths("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.0/library")
```

Veryfy it by `.libPaths()`